# Converting GETDATE() to string in SSIS

Tags: ssis

All,

I am trying to convert a simple getdate() to string. When I write the expression as (DT_STR,29,1252) GETDATE(), it gives me the error

"The expression (DT_STR,29,1252) GETDATE() has a result type of DT_STR, which cannot be converted to a supported type."

What is wrong with this. I just dont seem to understand what wrong am I doing here.

**EDIT**

Below is the screenshot of the expression that I am trying to evaluate.

[image]
Thanks,
RV

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the transformation window.

Comment: @TabAlleman Done.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see the part I want to see which is where you set the datatype of the output column.   But see if this helps:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8770221d-224d-412f-aa69-2cdaf99ccbb5/dtstr-error-message?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: This is an expression for a variable and not an output column. From what I read from the error message, DT_STR is not able to convert to itself because it is not supported? Thats the weirdest error I have seen all my life.

Comment: where is this expression? I originally thought you were in a derived column. but you aren't

Comment: Well as per the link I sent, I guess `29,1252` perhaps returns a unicode string, so you have to cast it as `DT_WSTR`.   So yeah, if that's the case, then your expression is literally contradicting itself.   Like if you tried casting "hello" as an integer.

Comment: What he was attempting to do does work in a data flow though in a derived column.

Comment: This is an expression for a variable @start_time with package level scope. I tried typecasting it to DT_WSTR,29 and now it tells me that it cannot convert "System.String' to 'System.DateTime'. SMH.

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable???   (it had better be string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS Variables of type string only offer the String data type - no AnsiString. AnsiString allows you to specify the codepage whereas String is unicode and doesn't support codepages.

Therefore, the expression should be

```
(DT_WSTR,29) GETDATE()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bill. I tried this and it gives me error that it cannot convert from System.String to System.Datetime. This is only an expression on a variable named @Start_Time.

Comment: Hi @rvphx Can you help me understand how the expression doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I think I got it. I had assigned the expression as DateTime datatype and was fiddling with it thinking it would convert to a string. Doh! Stupid me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `,1252` from your conversion Function.

Comment: That wont work. When converting to string (type DT_STR), the 1252 is a must for code page reference. Thats the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Check where are you trying to assign this expression to. If its a variable, make sure the variable has the EXACT same type as the one you are casting (in this case `STR`, not unicode - `WSTR` or `date` nor `datetime`). Make sure your variable type is a string for this case. Also keep in mind that a variable string is stored as unicode, if I recall correctly you can't change it, so it would need a cast to WSTR.

Also try to hard-code a value like `(DT_STR,29,1252) "myStringValue"` and see if it still raises the error. The problem is not the expression, is the type mismatch between the expression result and the place you are trying to store it.